# Android Exception "Cannot broadcast before boot completed"

Tags: java, android, exception

I got this error from the logs.

I keep searching on the web but no answers. I just want to know what causes this error.

Logs:

```
[java] java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
     [java] at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) 
     [java] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355) 
     [java] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222) 
     [java] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 
     [java] at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
     [java] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
     [java] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
     [java] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot broadcast before boot completed 
     [java] at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1473) 
     [java] at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419) 
     [java] at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2406) 
     [java] at android.app.ContextImpl.sendStickyBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1407) 
     [java] at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendStickyBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:427) 
     [java] at com.phoenix.server.utils.SwitchService.a(SourceFile:126) 
 [java] at com.phoenix.server.utils.SyncServerService$SyncHandler.a(SourceFile:79) 
 [java] at com.phoenix.server.utils.SyncServerService$SyncHandler.doInBackground(SourceFile:102) 
 [java] at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
 [java] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
 [java] ... 4 more
```

I executed the AsyncTask under a class extended by an Application, and inside the onCreate() method.

```
new AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {

                 SyncServerService.isLoaded(false);
                 startService(new Intent(context, SyncServerService.class));

                //wait BOOT COMPLETED broadcast.
                mStartUpRunnable.run();

                return null;
            }
        }.execute(this);
```

============

Under SyncServerService class service, onStartCommand returns START_NOT_STICKY. Is this causes the service class in sending a broadcast intent?

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: post your asyncTask code.

Comment: This might be Android core bug. This sometimes is also followed by soft-brick infinite boot animation... Do you have this error on the startup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Is there any issue on starting the service before the boot completed finishes? I can't see on my code that sends a broadcast before the boot completed.

Answer (score 0):

Use flag `Intent#FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY`

```
try {
  // send broadcast here.
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // set FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY and send again.
}
```